# There was a resource authorization issue: "The pipeline is not valid. > Job validate: Step TerraformTaskV1

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, azure-pipelines, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-template-file

I get this error in Azure devops pipeline when I split a yaml to make templates

> There was a resource authorization issue: "The pipeline is not valid.
> Job validate: Step TerraformTaskV1 input backendServiceArm references
> service connection azurerm which could not be found. The service
> connection does not exist or has not been authorized for use. For
> authorization details, refer to [https://aka.ms/yamlauthz."](https://aka.ms/yamlauthz.%22)

[here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/931131/the-pipeline-is-not-valid-service-connection-not-f.html) a solution is given to remove task and add again.  But it did not work for me.

When I had terraform in one yaml file, it worked.

```
stages:
  - stage: validate
    jobs:
    - job: validate
      continueOnError: false
      steps: 
      - task: TerraformInstaller@0
        displayName: 'install'
        inputs:
          terraformVersion: '0.12.26'
      - task: TerraformTaskV1@0
        displayName: init
        inputs:
          provider: 'azurerm'
          command: 'init'
          backendServiceArm: 'azure-spn'
          backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: 'terraform-rg'
          backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: 'adsstatetr'
          backendAzureRmContainerName: 'sktfcontainer'
          backendAzureRmKey: 'terraform.tfstate'
      - task: TerraformTaskV1@0
        displayName: validate
        inputs:
          provider: 'azurerm'
          command: 'validate'
```

When I split into two (templates)

```
stages:
  - stage: validate
    jobs:
    - template: terraform-validate.yml
      parameters:
        version: '0.12.26'
        sp: 'azurerm'
        rg: 'terraform-rg'
        sg: 'adsstatetr'
        sgContainer: 'sktfcontainer'
        skey: 'terraform.tfstate'
```

It failed and gave the error written above!

```
parameters:
 version: ''
 sp: ''
 rg: ''
 sg: ''
 sgContainer: ''
 skey: ''
jobs: 
  - job: validate
    continueOnError: false
    steps: 
    - task: TerraformInstaller@0
      displayName: 'install'
      inputs:
        terraformVersion: '0.12.26'
    - task: TerraformTaskV1@0
      inputs:
        provider: 'azurerm'
        command: 'init'
        backendServiceArm: '${{ parameters.sp }}'
        backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: '${{ parameters.rg }}'
        backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: '${{ parameters.sg }}'
        backendAzureRmContainerName: '${{ parameters.sgContainer }}'
        backendAzureRmKey: '${{ parameters.skey }}'
```

It also is showing a strange Authorize resource. clicking 'approve' does not fix either.  Again why? If there is any issue with service connection, why should my single file yaml work? There is no approval issue here! [image]

Comment: cant you just authorize it (click the button)?

Comment: As mentioned, I did and it didn't work

Comment: ok, how did it not work exactly?

Comment: It continued to show the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In working example as arm connection you pass `backendServiceArm: 'azure-spn'` and in template it is `sp: 'azurerm'`, so if you change to `sp: 'azure-spn'`, you should be fine.

Comment: @BlueClouds Can you consider upvoting my reply if it was helpful for you?

Answer (score 0):

your pipeline is not recognising any variable or parameter passed by you. if its recognising still there is issue than check the syntax. like if statement is not below stage, etc

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30559003)